# How to activate animations for layered SVG the moment it appears on viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, svg

I have researched on other stackoverflow questions regarding triggering animations after appearing on viewport but all similar questions only used single-layered SVG.

My SVG is layered (different sections) and thus I can't target (or rather, don't know how to) all sections of the SVG at once the moment it appears on viewport.

Here's a Codepen of what I'm referring to: https://codepen.io/aahlfeeyann/full/rmLmKE/

```
<svg class="birthday-cake" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 58 53" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <!--Generated by IJSVG (https://github.com/curthard89/IJSVG)-->
            <defs>
                <path id="path-4" d="M0,0v6"></path>
                <path id="path-6" d="M3,3l-3,-3"></path>
                <path id="path-1" d="M12.5,0c0,3.452 -2.798,6.25 -6.25,6.25c-3.452,0 -6.25,-2.798 -6.25,-6.25"></path>
                <path id="path-3" d="M0,5h10.45c-0.133,-2.781 -2.411,-5 -5.225,-5c-2.814,0 -5.092,2.219 -5.225,5v0Z"></path>
                <path id="path-2" d="M10.45,0h-10.45c0.133,2.781 2.411,5 5.225,5c2.814,0 5.092,-2.219 5.225,-5v0Z"></path>
                <path id="path-5" d="M0,3l3,-3"></path>
            </defs>
            <g transform="translate(-841, -1680)">
                <g transform="translate(842, 1681)">
                    <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2">

                        <!-- Candles -->
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(16, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(23, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(30, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(37, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(37, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(30, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(23, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                        <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(16, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>      

                        <!-- Main Cake Shape -->
                        <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M50,14h-50v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h46c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(3, 34)"></path>
                        <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M42,14h-42v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h38c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(7, 20)"></path>
                        <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M34,14h-34v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h30c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(11, 6)"></path>                    

                        <!-- 1st Layer Deco -->
                        <path class="first-deco animate" d="M4.475,0h-4.475c0.133,2.781 2.411,5 5.225,5c0.433,0 0.847,-0.067 1.25,-0.166v-2.834c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2v0Z" transform="translate(38.525, 6)"></path>
                        <path class="first-deco animate" d="M1.25,5c2.814,0 5.092,-2.219 5.225,-5h-4.475c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v2.834c0.403,0.099 0.817,0.166 1.25,0.166v0Z" transform="translate(11, 6)"></path>

                        <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(17.525, 6)" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                        <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(28.025, 6)" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                        <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(28.025, 15)" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                        <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(17.525, 15)" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>

                        <path class="first-deco animate" d="M2,5h4.475c-0.133,-2.781 -2.411,-5 -5.225,-5c-0.433,0 -0.847,0.067 -1.25,0.166v2.834c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2v0Z" transform="translate(11, 15)"></path>
                        <path class="first-deco animate" d="M5.225,0c-2.814,0 -5.092,2.219 -5.225,5h4.475c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2v-2.834c-0.403,-0.099 -0.817,-0.166 -1.25,-0.166v0Z" transform="translate(38.525, 15)"></path>

                        <!-- 2nd Layer Deco -->
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(10, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(14, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(18, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(22, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(26, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(30, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(34, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(38, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(42, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                        <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(46, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>

                        <!-- 3rd Layer Deco -->
                        <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(3, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                        <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(15.5, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                        <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(28, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                        <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(40.5, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>

                        <!-- Bottom Plate -->
                        <path class="bottom-plate animate" d="M0,0h56" transform="translate(0, 48)"></path>
                        <path class="bottom-plate animate" d="M0,0h48" transform="translate(4, 51)"></path>    

                    </g>
                </g>
            </g>
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You said you want to animate all the layers at once or you want to get access to them? or you want to get access to one of them and then animate it? what is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will help you to animate the cake when you scrolldown. I'm using [ScrollMagic v2.0.5](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/index.html) for the scroll detection.
First, you need to init the controller`:

```
var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
```

Then you build the `scene` adding `setClassToggle` for the action and `addTo` to add the `controller`:

```
var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({triggerElement: "#trigger", duration: 300});
scene.setClassToggle("#birthday-cake", "ontrigger");
scene.addTo(controller);
```

I added an `id="trigger"`  to the `div` that has an `info-title` class:

And finally in the `CSS` I removed the `animation-name: draw;` from the `.animate` class and I created a `.ontrigger .animate` rule:

```
.ontrigger .animate{
    animation-name: draw;
}
```

**Update**

The idea to use **ScrollMagic** is to control when do you want to trigger an `event` also you can control how many times do you want to trigger that event.

So I replaced the `scene.setClassToggle()` with [the `on()` method](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#on) to add two more event listeners. The first event will be when the trigger `enter` to the middle of the screen and the other event will be at the `end`.

```
scene.on('enter', function(e) {
  ...
})
scene.on('end', function(e) {
  ...
});
```

The last element is that we need to remove the controller from the `scene` using [the `remove()` method](http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#remove) so it will stop triggering the `enter` and `end` events

This is the implementation in [Codepen](https://codepen.io/teocci/full/QvEQPZ)

```js
$(function() { // wait for document ready
  // init controller
  var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();

  // build scene
  var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
    triggerElement: "#trigger",
    duration: 300
  });

  scene.on('enter', function(e) {
    console.log('onEnter');
    $('#birthday-cake').addClass('ontrigger');
  });

  scene.on('end', function(e) {
    console.log('onEnd');
    scene.remove();
  });

  scene.addTo(controller);
});
```

```css
h4{
    font-size: 1.750em;
}


.info-box{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    
    margin: 50px 0;
    
    border: 1px solid burlywood;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.info-box:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.info-title{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.info-title p{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

/* Cake Panel */
svg{
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.animate {
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #000;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.ontrigger .animate {
    animation-name: draw;
}
.candles{
    stroke-dasharray: 5;
    stroke-dashoffset: 5;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.cake-shape{
    stroke-dasharray: 140;
    stroke-dashoffset: 140;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
.first-deco{
    stroke-dasharray: 140;
    stroke-dashoffset: 140;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}
.second-deco{
    stroke-dasharray: 10;
    stroke-dashoffset: 10;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}
.third-deco{
    stroke-dasharray: 40;
    stroke-dashoffset: 40;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}
.bottom-plate{
    stroke-dasharray: 60;
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}

/* Icon Keyframes*/
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

/* Footer */
footer{
    min-width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.hero{
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.hero p{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,400i|Playfair+Display:900" rel="stylesheet">

<body>

  <!-- Hero -->
  <div class="hero">
    <p>FULL SCREEN DIV</p>
  </div>

  <!-- Main Content -->
  <section class="detail">
    <h1 class="section-header">What We Do</h1>

    <div class="info-box">
      <div id="trigger" class="info-title">
        <h4>We have the greatest collections of cakes</h4>
        <p>Our cakes are oven-baked to golden-brown, with handpicked ingredients to ensure 100% quality.</p>
      </div>
      <svg id="birthday-cake" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 58 53" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
        <!--Generated by IJSVG (https://github.com/curthard89/IJSVG)-->
        <defs>
          <path id="path-4" d="M0,0v6"></path>
          <path id="path-6" d="M3,3l-3,-3"></path>
          <path id="path-1" d="M12.5,0c0,3.452 -2.798,6.25 -6.25,6.25c-3.452,0 -6.25,-2.798 -6.25,-6.25"></path>
          <path id="path-3" d="M0,5h10.45c-0.133,-2.781 -2.411,-5 -5.225,-5c-2.814,0 -5.092,2.219 -5.225,5v0Z"></path>
          <path id="path-2" d="M10.45,0h-10.45c0.133,2.781 2.411,5 5.225,5c2.814,0 5.092,-2.219 5.225,-5v0Z"></path>
          <path id="path-5" d="M0,3l3,-3"></path>
        </defs>
        <g transform="translate(-841, -1680)">
          <g transform="translate(842, 1681)">
            <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2">
              <!-- Candles -->
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(16, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(23, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(30, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(37, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(37, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(30, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(23, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
              <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(16, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>

              <!-- Main Cake Shape -->
              <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M50,14h-50v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h46c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(3, 34)"></path>
              <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M42,14h-42v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h38c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(7, 20)"></path>
              <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M34,14h-34v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h30c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(11, 6)"></path>
              <!-- 1st Layer Deco -->
              <path class="first-deco animate" d="M4.475,0h-4.475c0.133,2.781 2.411,5 5.225,5c0.433,0 0.847,-0.067 1.25,-0.166v-2.834c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2v0Z" transform="translate(38.525, 6)"></path>
              <path class="first-deco animate" d="M1.25,5c2.814,0 5.092,-2.219 5.225,-5h-4.475c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v2.834c0.403,0.099 0.817,0.166 1.25,0.166v0Z" transform="translate(11, 6)"></path>

              <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(17.525, 6)" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
              <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(28.025, 6)" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
              <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(28.025, 15)" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
              <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(17.525, 15)" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>

              <path class="first-deco animate" d="M2,5h4.475c-0.133,-2.781 -2.411,-5 -5.225,-5c-0.433,0 -0.847,0.067 -1.25,0.166v2.834c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2v0Z" transform="translate(11, 15)"></path>
              <path class="first-deco animate" d="M5.225,0c-2.814,0 -5.092,2.219 -5.225,5h4.475c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2v-2.834c-0.403,-0.099 -0.817,-0.166 -1.25,-0.166v0Z" transform="translate(38.525, 15)"></path>

              <!-- 2nd Layer Deco -->
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(10, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(14, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(18, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(22, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(26, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(30, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(34, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(38, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(42, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
              <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(46, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>

              <!-- 3rd Layer Deco -->
              <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(3, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
              <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(15.5, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
              <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(28, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
              <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(40.5, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>

              <!-- Bottom Plate -->
              <path class="bottom-plate animate" d="M0,0h56" transform="translate(0, 48)"></path>
              <path class="bottom-plate animate" d="M0,0h48" transform="translate(4, 51)"></path>

            </g>
          </g>
        </g>
      </svg>
    </div>

    <div class="info-box">
      <div class="info-title">
        <h4>Our cookies are irresistible</h4>
        <p>From almonds to hazelnuts, we have a variety of mouth-watering cookies for you to choose from. </p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="info-box">
      <div class="info-title">
        <h4>Island-wide outlets to cater to your needs</h4>
        <p>We have 40 outlets islandwide, so you don't worry about not finding an outlet near you!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <!-- Footer -->
  <footer>
  </footer>

  <!-- Scripts -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/ScrollMagic.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ScrollMagic/2.0.5/plugins/debug.addIndicators.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, works the best so far.  The only problem I have now is for the svg to stop re-animating every single time the viewport captures the `info-title` class. Meaning, the animation will only be done the first time the user scrolls past the `info-title` class. Any ideas how to do that? Otherwise, your solution is the best so far. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Pick your favourite bit of JS code to determine when your SVG is on screen. Then have it add a class to the SVG that will trigger the animation.

Then make sure your animation CSS rules only trigger when the SVG has the "onscreen" class.

```
.animate{
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #000;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}

.onscreen .animate{
    animation-name: draw;
}
```

Example here:

```js
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
  $("#birthday-cake").addClass("onscreen");
  // Note: addClass() on SVG elements requires jQuery 2.2+
})
```

```css
h4{
    font-size: 1.750em;
}


.info-box{
    width: 400px;
    height: 500px;
    
    margin: 50px 0;
    
    border: 1px solid burlywood;
    border-radius: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.4s;
}

.info-box:hover{
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 50px -10px rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

.info-title{
    margin-top: 30px;
}

.info-title p{
    width: 70%;
    margin: 30px auto;
}

/* Cake Panel */
svg{
    max-width: 60%;
    max-height: 60%;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
.animate{
    stroke-width: 2;
    stroke: #000;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    animation-iteration-count: 1;
    animation-timing-function: linear;
}
.onscreen .animate{
    animation-name: draw;
}
.candles{
    stroke-dasharray: 5;
    stroke-dashoffset: 5;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s;
}
.cake-shape{
    stroke-dasharray: 140;
    stroke-dashoffset: 140;
    animation-duration: 2s;
}
.first-deco{
    stroke-dasharray: 140;
    stroke-dashoffset: 140;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}
.second-deco{
    stroke-dasharray: 10;
    stroke-dashoffset: 10;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}
.third-deco{
    stroke-dasharray: 40;
    stroke-dashoffset: 40;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}
.bottom-plate{
    stroke-dasharray: 60;
    stroke-dashoffset: 60;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-delay: 2s
}

/* Icon Keyframes*/
@keyframes draw {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

/* Footer */
footer{
    min-width: 100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color: burlywood;
}

.hero{
  height: 100vh;
  width:100%;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.hero p{
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
<div class="info-box">
                <div class="info-title">
                    <h4>We have the greatest collections of cakes</h4>
                    <p>Our cakes are oven-baked to golden-brown, with handpicked ingredients to ensure 100% quality.</p>
                </div>
                <svg id="birthday-cake" version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 58 53" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
            <!--Generated by IJSVG (https://github.com/curthard89/IJSVG)-->
                <defs>
                    <path id="path-4" d="M0,0v6"></path>
                    <path id="path-6" d="M3,3l-3,-3"></path>
                    <path id="path-1" d="M12.5,0c0,3.452 -2.798,6.25 -6.25,6.25c-3.452,0 -6.25,-2.798 -6.25,-6.25"></path>
                    <path id="path-3" d="M0,5h10.45c-0.133,-2.781 -2.411,-5 -5.225,-5c-2.814,0 -5.092,2.219 -5.225,5v0Z"></path>
                    <path id="path-2" d="M10.45,0h-10.45c0.133,2.781 2.411,5 5.225,5c2.814,0 5.092,-2.219 5.225,-5v0Z"></path>
                    <path id="path-5" d="M0,3l3,-3"></path>
                </defs>
                <g transform="translate(-841, -1680)">
                    <g transform="translate(842, 1681)">
                        <g fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd" stroke="#000" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2">
                            <!-- Candles -->
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(16, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(23, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(30, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(37, 0)" xlink:href="#path-5"></use>
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(37, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(30, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(23, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>
                            <use class="candles animate" transform="translate(16, 0)" xlink:href="#path-6"></use>      
                            
                            <!-- Main Cake Shape -->
                            <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M50,14h-50v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h46c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(3, 34)"></path>
                            <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M42,14h-42v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h38c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(7, 20)"></path>
                            <path class="cake-shape animate" d="M34,14h-34v-12c0,-1.1 0.9,-2 2,-2h30c1.1,0 2,0.9 2,2v12v0Z" transform="translate(11, 6)"></path>                    
                            <!-- 1st Layer Deco -->
                            <path class="first-deco animate" d="M4.475,0h-4.475c0.133,2.781 2.411,5 5.225,5c0.433,0 0.847,-0.067 1.25,-0.166v-2.834c0,-1.1 -0.9,-2 -2,-2v0Z" transform="translate(38.525, 6)"></path>
                            <path class="first-deco animate" d="M1.25,5c2.814,0 5.092,-2.219 5.225,-5h-4.475c-1.1,0 -2,0.9 -2,2v2.834c0.403,0.099 0.817,0.166 1.25,0.166v0Z" transform="translate(11, 6)"></path>
                            
                            <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(17.525, 6)" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                            <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(28.025, 6)" xlink:href="#path-2"></use>
                            <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(28.025, 15)" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                            <use class="first-deco animate" transform="translate(17.525, 15)" xlink:href="#path-3"></use>
                            
                            <path class="first-deco animate" d="M2,5h4.475c-0.133,-2.781 -2.411,-5 -5.225,-5c-0.433,0 -0.847,0.067 -1.25,0.166v2.834c0,1.1 0.9,2 2,2v0Z" transform="translate(11, 15)"></path>
                            <path class="first-deco animate" d="M5.225,0c-2.814,0 -5.092,2.219 -5.225,5h4.475c1.1,0 2,-0.9 2,-2v-2.834c-0.403,-0.099 -0.817,-0.166 -1.25,-0.166v0Z" transform="translate(38.525, 15)"></path>
                            
                            <!-- 2nd Layer Deco -->
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(10, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(14, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(18, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(22, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(26, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(30, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(34, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(38, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(42, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            <use class="second-deco animate" transform="translate(46, 24)" xlink:href="#path-4"></use>
                            
                            <!-- 3rd Layer Deco -->
                            <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(3, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                            <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(15.5, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                            <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(28, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                            <use class="third-deco animate" transform="translate(40.5, 37.75)" xlink:href="#path-1"></use>
                                                      
                            <!-- Bottom Plate -->
                            <path class="bottom-plate animate" d="M0,0h56" transform="translate(0, 48)"></path>
                            <path class="bottom-plate animate" d="M0,0h48" transform="translate(4, 51)"></path>    
                                           
                        </g>
                    </g>
                </g>
</svg>
              <button id="test">Trigger onscreesn</button>
            </div>
```

Comment: As a newbie coder I fail to realise how simple it is to trigger a CSS separately with a class like you've shown! Your JavaScript button gave me a few ideas too, thanks!